# Center specific li in div with hidden overflow

Tags: jquery, css, math, center

I have a div of 1200px wide, inside that div I have another div with hidden overflow. This div has a random amount of images positioned next to each other. The images are also random in size. It's like a carousal: the image in the middle of the 1200px div is the active image; on the sides of that image you can see another image. If the user clicks either of those images, I animate the margin of the UL element the images are in so that the clicked image is centered in the 1200px div. My current method doesn't perfectly center the selected image, does anyone here have a formula I could use?

Right now, I use this to calculate the new margin-left value (to go left):

```
    parseInt($('.images').css('margin-left')) - parseInt((active.width() / 2) + target.width() / 2)
```

Considering my math skills are very poor, I'm hoping someone can come up with something better.

Per request, the HTML and CSS:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div class="inside">
            <ul class="images">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" width="550" height="550" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li class="activeimg">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" width="550" height="367" alt=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/3.jpg" width="370" height="550" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/4.jpg" width="393" height="550" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/5.jpg" width="550" height="356" alt="" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
#slideshow {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1200px;
height: 600px;
background-color: #525252;
margin-top: 100px;
border:1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}

#slideshow .inside {
height: 550px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 25px 0;
}

#slideshow ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
transition: margin 1s;
-moz-transition: margin 1s;
-webkit-transition: margin 1s;
-o-transition: margin 1s;
}
#slideshow li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please post the CSS and the HTML too.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new class `.c-img` and using javascript just add/remove this class from `li`.

```
.c-img {
position:fixed;
margin:(...your calculated margin);
}
```

Try doing this in http://jsfiddle.net and link results here.

Comment: But my calculated margin is off, that's what I'm really looking for: a better way to calculate the margin.

Comment: @Galadre : if you want image to be centred then use `margin: 0 auto` instead of calculating margin manually.

Comment: No, the selected li has to be centered but the UL has a width that is greater than the visible viewport. So the UL has to have the correct margin for the user-selected li to be centered in the viewport. Each time the user selects a different li element, that li needs to be centered in hte viewport. Hope that makes sense..